# SVN using MacOS, Linux, and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, macos, user-interface, svn

For a long term university project involving a small team (2/5 people), 
using Matlab and Java, we are trying to set up an SVN.

The problem is that the computers used in this project run different OS. 
The main computer where the code should be compiled and tested  in the laboratory runs Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
our supervisor, which would have admin rights uses MacOS, while the other computers would have either Windows or MacOS.

As we are not familiar with SVN, I believe it would be better chose a programme with a comprehensive GUI such as 
smartSVN. The difficulty lies in finding an opensource that works across all platforms or at least Mac and Linux.

Is there any other free software, with GUI,  that you'd suggest?

Thank you!

Comment: You can choose any SVN client on any platform, svn clients are basically representing data by getting it from SVN server. So, in your case svn-server can be installed on ubuntu and tortoise svn can be used for windows machine, smartSVN can be used for mac and command line svn tool for ubuntu.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because this is a programming site. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with multiple SVN clients on the same remote repository. The GUI of a client is just a visual layer of the svn protocol.

You can use tortoiseSVN on Windows, smartSVN on Mac, an integrated client inside your IDE on Linux, or whatever you want.

In your case, you should have only the source code in your repository and a different configuration on the computers.